# A continuous image of a closed interval is bounded

Tags: general-topology, analysis

I know that one way of proving this is to recognize the continuous image of a closed interval as a compact subset of $\mathbb R$, which is then bounded. But I am trying to give out an alternative proof.

Let $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb R$ be continuous. $O(x)=\{x'\in [a,b]:|f(x)-f(x')|<1\}$ is open as $f$ is continuous. Then $\{O(x):x\in[a,b]\}$ is an open cover of $[a,b].$ By the Heine-Borel property, there exist a finite subcover of $O(x_1),...O(x_k).$ Then by triangle inequality, we may conclude $|f(x)|<\max\{|f(x_1)|,...,|f(x_k)|\}+1.$ (The above proof is given by Basic Topology, Armstrong.)

However, my problem is that how can we know that each of $f(x_i)$ does not tend to infinity? If  It seems like a circular reasoning to me since we just persume the arbitrary $f(x_i)$ is bounded, which is what we are trying to prove.

Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: The number of $x_i$ is finite, so you can’t go to infinity

Comment: I mean if one of $f(x_i)$ tends to infinity

Comment: it’s not possible because f is a function in \mathbb{R} and so it not makes sense that the evaluation is equal to \infty

Comment: They are *numbers*. They don't go anywhere.

Comment: Thank you a lot. I just realize I make a very stupid mistake..

Comment: $[0,\infty)$ is a closed interval. The function $x\mapsto x$ is continuous. The image of $[0,\infty)$ under that continuous map is not bounded.